# How to figure out which library a native JNI function is calling?

Tags: android, libraries

I'm trying to perform static analysis on Android framework code, and I'm coming across some Java methods that are calling JNI functions. How do I figure out which native libraries these functions reside in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't touched Android in almost a year but IIRC:

All JNI libraries need to be loaded from Java side first e.g.

```
System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
```

which translates to `invoke-virtual` in compiled Java.

Also, IDA Pro identifies fully qualified names in `.so`s it decompiles, so you will be able to figure out Java names for those JNI functions. See also http://www.hexblog.com/?p=809.

This tool may also be of help, although it's rather old https://github.com/maaaaz/jnianalyzer.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but there should be a static code block with the .so they are calling. I would need to disassemble a file using a shared library.

It will resemble:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437106/java-jni-call-to-load-library

Comment: Thanks. In the example given, would the static library be libndkfoo.so?